# Ubuntu kernal update 5.0.9

Tags: 18.04, kernel

Running Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility from USC and it now advises that Linux version 5.0.9 is available for download (currently running 4.18.0.17.18).

[image]

Is it advisable to use the utility to install this version or will it eventually become available?

I'm guided by [this old thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) which suggests that new kernels are automatically advised by Ubuntu's Software Updater which loads it in the background so, should I just be patient and wait until it happens rather than force the issue?

Comment: don't try to fix things that are not broken. Is there any reason for you to need 5.0.9?

Comment: @Rinzwind Nope. Just that the utility persists in telling me that a new version is available. Beginning to wonder whether best to set it to not advise new versions or just remove the utility altogether.

Comment: It is not advisable to use UKUU, unless you have a good reason to use it, and from the question above, it looks like there is no reason at all.

Comment: @Graham ignore it ;-)  I know it itches :D :D and it took me a year or 2 to accept to just ignore it.

Comment: Kernel 5.0.x is available in the latest 19.04 that was just released. That's the best way to get a newer kernel. If this is a production/work computer, don't manually update it to 5.0.9. If this is a personal machine, and you have good backups, then go ahead and install 5.0.9... but expect problems... and don't expect security updates from the Ubuntu folks... or support.